# Delete data from large table efficiently

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am running below query to delete data from a very large table.

```
delete from
  schema2.table2 using schema1.table1
where
  schema2.table2.timestamp2 <= schema1.table1.timestamp2
  and schema2.table2.id = schema1.table1.id;
```

This query is using hash join for data deletion and scanning more than 3 TBs of data. Reason being out of these 2 columns, none of them are either sort or dist key.

We have 2 timestamp columns in the table, timestamp1(our sort key) we use for select queries and timestamp2 for insertion and deletion.

I solution I can think of is to separate these queries, so first we select the data from 1st table and then delete it from 2nd table in batches:

```
WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (condition for deleting))

BEGIN
SET ROWCOUNT 1000
DELETE Table2 WHERE (condition for deleting)
SET ROWCOUNT 0
END
```

but I am not sure how efficient this option is.

Please suggest me what would be the best way to delete data efficiently?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficiently"? Does the DELETE successfully run? What is your particular concern -- is it taking too long, or perhaps failing?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a new table for the rows you will keep instead of deleting the rows. Delete is always costly no matter which db you use.

if your table is called `schema2.table2`  you can use the following

```
create table schema2.table3 as
select t2.* from
  schema2.table2 t2, schema1.table1 t1
where
  t2.timestamp2 > t1.timestamp2
  and t2.id = t1.id;

drop table schema2.table2;
alter table schema2.table3 rename to schema2.table2;
```